# use of .html in jQuery question?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load my controllerMostrarMayorContenido in to an area(div ) on my page(index) and I can load pure text all, I read that It is using .html, It just retrieving the contents of my controller and paste it in index.php, I already do it in mootools but I dont find a way in jquery, It does not work

**the problem is with this line 
document.getElementById('divrespuesta2').innerHTML= texto;**

in moootools It works

```
  var prueboRequest = new Request({
   method: 'POST',
//   data: 'id_tema='+id_tema,
   url: '../controller/controllerTema/controllerMostrarMayorContenido.php',
   onRequest: function() {}, 
   onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta){
   document.getElementById('divrespuesta2').innerHTML= texto; this line

   },
   onFailure: function(){alert('Fallo');}
}).send();
}
```

in jQuery no

```
function limpiarDiv(id_tema){
     document.getElementById("divrespuesta2").innerHTML="";
     document.getElementById("divrespuesta3").innerHTML="";

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '../controller/controllerTema/controllerMostrarMayorContenido.php',
            beforeSend:function(){alert('ejecutandose');},
            success: function(){
                //document.getElementById('divrespuesta2').innerHTML= texto; 
                $('#divrespuesta2').html('texto');
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument in the `ajax` success handler is the response returned by the server resource. Try this

```
function limpiarDiv(id_tema){
     document.getElementById("divrespuesta2").innerHTML="";
     document.getElementById("divrespuesta3").innerHTML="";

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '../controller/controllerTema/controllerMostrarMayorContenido.php',
            beforeSend:function(){alert('ejecutandose');},
            success: function(response){
                //document.getElementById('divrespuesta2').innerHTML= texto; 
                $('#divrespuesta2').html(response);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: thanks for answering I understand better the error all othe question another comments aboout .html?? I already trying to understand

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems in your jquery code:

- It should be `$('#divrespuesta2').html(texto);` since you want the value of texto and not texto as text
- You need to pass `texto` to your success callback function, it should look like this: `success: function(texto) { ... }`

Comment: another comments aboout .html??